# In android Why my ProgressBar Freezes?

Tags: android, progress-bar

i am showing Progress Bar at time of retrieving data from server and after retrieving data from server showing that data on chart but at time of plotting that data on chart my progress bar get freezes does any one have idea why this is so......

THANKS in advance...

```
private ProgressDialog pd;
private Handler handler = new Handler() {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {        
        Toast.makeText(context, "Please Wait...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {              
            @Override
            public void run() {
                functionDrawMyData();/*in this function i am accessing activity view and drawing data on that view at time of drawing my Progress bar Freezes */
            }
        });
        runOnUiThread(t);
        pd.dismiss();           
    }
};
```

this handler i am using which is called after retrieving data finished
and on button click i am getting data and showing progress bar

```
ImageButton myButton = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.myBtn);
pair1ChartButton.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {               
                pd = ProgressDialog.show(v.getContext(),"Please wait...","Retrieving data ...",true,
                        true,
                        new DialogInterface.OnCancelListener(){
                            @Override
                            public void onCancel(DialogInterface dialog) {

                            }
                        });
                Thread t = new Thread(new Runnable() {                      
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                            getDataFromServer();//calling function to get data from server
                        handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);                    
                    }
                });
                t.start();
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 3):

Remember android keeps the reference of dilogs in the memory. so that it does not need to recreate it again and again. so progress dialog works fine for the first time but hung/stuck for next time.

**NOTE:** android does not clear memory references of dilogs even after dismissing them.

there is method is `Activity` class named as `removeDialog(int id)` this will also clear memory references.

Here is how you can display and remove dialog

```
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        switch(id){
          case 0:{
             dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", 
                    "Loading. Please wait...", true);
             return dialog;
          }
             }

        return super.onCreateDialog(id);
    }
```

Now just call `showDialog(0)` to display dialog and `removeDialog(0)` to hide it.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It should be noted though, that ProgressDialog is deprecated and should be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

This is because you are starting to update your UI even before you close or dismiss your dialog. This is the reason for your progressDialog freeze.

So Change your code like this,

```
     pd.dismiss();  
    runOnUiThread(t);
```

Comment: Then you have to dismiss the old dialog and start a new progress dialog before calling runOnUiThread(t).

Answer (score 0):

Same problem i too faced,i solved my self,

Just see my sample code. you will understand.

```
public class NearByLoc extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    @SuppressLint("InlinedApi")
    protected void onPreExecute() {

        // pdailog.show();
        loading_spinnerMain.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }


@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
     //write your entire code [logic]here

  }
@Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {

        //finally list of data setting to the adapter
        //before setting to the adapter you should dismiss Progress spinnerr 

        loading_spinnerMain.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        NearByMeAdapter adapter = new NearByMeAdapter(NearByMe.this, list);

        listViewNearLoc.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```

Its worked for me..Hope it helps you