# Display progress bar while waiting the location to be obtained

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [In android Why my ProgressBar Freezes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8322311/in-android-why-my-progressbar-freezes)

Can anyone help me display progress bar as long as the location is not obtained so that the user cannon proceed until the location is clear..
my code is like this :

```
        // Initialize the location variables
    if (location != null) {
        dist_lat = location.getLatitude();
        dist_long = location.getLongitude();
    } else {
            //I want to display the progress bar here.. 
            }
```

Thank you soo much in advance ..

Answer (score 0):

I would do something like this, you actually have to start the dialog/progress bar before you start attempting to obtain your information.  Once that is started, spawn a new thread to grab your data.  Inside the thread, after you receive your data, then close the dialog/progress bar.

Ex.  Put this in your else block

```
ProgressDialog dialog = new ProgressDialog(YourClassName.this);
        dialog.show(YourClassName.this, "", "Loading...", true);

        new Thread(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                //Grab your results here.... then close the dialog
                 dialog.dismiss()


                }
            }
        }).start();
```

Comment: I really appreciate your help tkcsam ..
Thank you so much.. 
I know who to start/stop threads based on timing .. can u help me to do what you have suggest in your answer ?